# Print document from webView using Xamarin forms on both Android and iOS platform

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I have displayed a document retrieved from HTML string on WebView using a custom renderer. Now want to print the document, have tried using https://github.com/codemillmatt/xam-forms-ez-print but the alignment is an issue.

The print alignment is causing an issue, it doesn't fit in any page size. It should fit A4 size.

Would be thankful on any help provided.

Comment: When, you say you want to print a document what exactly do you expect? Print the current screen or print the document that is open in your app or something of that sort please explain!

Comment: Want to print the document that is open in the webView.